# Need a board where the cells can be selected

Tags: swing

I'm planning to create a 7x7 board in Swing where I should be able to select the cell or highlight the cell by clicking on it. I should also be able to click/highlight multiple cells.

I tried using `GridLayout` but I'm not sure what kind of components I can add to it so that I can select them.

Can GridLayout be used for this or is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case, if anybody comes across such cases, I did use `GridLayout` and I used `JButton`s on it with `setOpaque(false)`. This will make it look like a board!